# After peering 2 nodes i am now trying to send ether to the other node but i am getting the below error

Tags: transactions

After peering 2 nodes i am now trying to send ether to the other node but i am getting the below error :

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.coinbase, to: "0xc7d0aa54e81d394e4b9e9dce74508bc75a66fdb5", value: web3.toWei(10, “ether”)})
(anonymous): Line 1:114 Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

(and 5 more errors after this one)

Can you please help ?

Regards
Shibu

Comment: Are the quotation marks you used for "ether" here straight quotes or angled quotes as is pasted in? That could be the source of error.